# Pandas: milliseconds dropped when writing data to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I'm trying to get a `DataFrame` with millisecond timestamps into a `MySQL` database. However, when doing this, the millisecond part seems to be dropped. I've created a working example to show what's going on:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine # database connection

#Generate date_time with millisecond resolution and price column
df=pd.DataFrame({'date_time' : pd.date_range('1/1/2000 09:00:00', freq="5ms",periods=100),'price' : np.random.random_sample(100)})

#Connect with an empty MySQL database (which I simply created using CREATE DATABASE trading_db;)
disk_engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:"+'MYPASSWORD'+"@localhost/trading_db")

#Dataframe to SQL in a Table called trading_data
df.to_sql('trading_data', disk_engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)

#When I read this back from MySQL, the milliseconds seem to dissapear
df_sql = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT *'
                   'FROM trading_data '
                   'LIMIT 20', disk_engine)
```

Compare the date-times of the `DataFrame`  created in `pandas`  with the ones loaded from `MySQL`:

```
df.head()

    date_time                   price
0   2000-01-01 09:00:00         0.371986
1   2000-01-01 09:00:00.005000  0.625551
2   2000-01-01 09:00:00.010000  0.631182
3   2000-01-01 09:00:00.015000  0.625316
4   2000-01-01 09:00:00.020000  0.522437

df_sql.head()

    date_time           price
0   2000-01-01 09:00:00 0.371986
1   2000-01-01 09:00:00 0.625551
2   2000-01-01 09:00:00 0.631182
3   2000-01-01 09:00:00 0.625316
4   2000-01-01 09:00:00 0.522437
```

As you can clearly see the milliseconds are dropped. Is there any way I can alter the code to keep the millisecond part?

Edit: I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.2 and pandas 0.14.1

Comment: You need to be on [v5.6.4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)+ to support fractional time values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you need MySQL v5.6.4+ for fractional seconds support ([docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html)).
But, as the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html) explain,  you need to specify this explicitly as `DATETIME(fsp)`, where `fsp` is the fractional seconds precision, to enable this in the datetime column.

The default in `to_sql` is to just use [`DateTime`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.DateTime) (the default sqlalchemy datetime type). You can however override this default with the `dtype` argument and use the [MySQL specific `DATETIME`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.DATETIME) type specifying the precision:

```
In [11]: from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import DATETIME

In [12]: df.to_sql('trading_data', engine, dtype={'date_time': DATETIME(fsp=6)}, if_exists='replace', index=False)

In [13]: df_sql = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM trading_data', engine)

In [14]: df_sql.head()
Out[14]:
                   date_time     price
0        2000-01-01 09:00:00  0.152087
1 2000-01-01 09:00:00.005000  0.927375
2 2000-01-01 09:00:00.010000  0.540021
3 2000-01-01 09:00:00.015000  0.499529
4 2000-01-01 09:00:00.020000  0.797420
```

Note: you need pandas 0.15.2+ for this `dtype` argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I updated to pandas 0.16.1 and using the dtype argument now works. However, I downloaded the newest version of MySQL Workbench (6.2) and the newest SQL version there is 5.6.24 (I'm an absolute beginner w.r.t. databases for the record). When I run `df.to_sql` and I look in the MySQL Workbench, then I see that there are indeed 6 places for fractional seconds but they are all zero. Moreover, when I then use `pd.read_sql_query`, I get back all None's for the date-time column. Would you have any idea how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: But the dates itself are correct? Further, what version of sqlalchemy are you using, and which driver? As the sqlalchemy docs (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/dialects/mysql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.DATETIME) say that not all drivers support the fractional seconds. I used `pymysql` (so but don't know if it would work with eg `MySQLdb`)

Comment: I'm using `SQLAlchemy` 1.0.4-1. However, I just installed `PyMySQL` 0.6.6-1 and now everything works perfectly (`MySQLdb` didn't though)!

Comment: What might be wrong that I don't get this work now either.

        dtype={'start_timestamp': sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.DATETIME(fsp=6),
                  'end_timestamp': sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.DATETIME(fsp=6)}

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem while using MSSQL.
I Changed SQL Driver from:

quote_plus('**DRIVER={SQL Server}**;SERVER=' + sqlserver + ';DATABASE=' + db2 + ';UID=' + user + ';PWD=' + passwd)

to:

quoted = quote_plus('**DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}**;SERVER=' + sqlserver + ';DATABASE=' + db2 + ';UID=' + user + ';PWD=' + passwd)

Comment: Since the OP is using MySQL, not MSSQL, I don't see how this will help.

Comment: I just sent my experience. Maybe someone faced the same problem as mine while using MSSQL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Respectfully, I have editd my previous answer to be more clear.