# Insert panda's timestamps without miliseconds into SQLite

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, datetime, sqlalchemy

I pull data from an Oracle database into a `DataFrame` with `pd.read_sql_query`. The resulting columns are of type `Timestamp` and contain only date+time. I then insert them with `DataFrame.to_sql` and `sqlarchemy` into an SQLite database and this step adds miliseconds when serialized to SQLite's `TEXT` column that I'd like to get rid of.

Is there an easy way to instruct `sqlalchemy` or panda's `to_sql` to serialize only date+time without adding 0 miliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out! You need to use `to_sql`'s `dtype` parameter and specify the format for each column by using the appropriate dialect type:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite import DATETIME

dtype={
    "DATETIME_COLUMN": DATETIME(storage_format="%(year)04d/%(month)02d/%(day)02d %(hour)02d:%(minute)02d:%(second)02d")
}
data.to_sql("table_name", session.connection(), if_exists="append", index=False, dtype=dtype)
```

where `session: sqlalchemy.orm.Session`

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/sqlite.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.DATETIME

---

A similar question with the opposite issue [Pandas: milliseconds dropped when writing data to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30328548/235671) put me on the right track.